# How do I change content and background color for a box on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fadein, fadeout

This is my first time tackling this so please correct me if my terminology for this wrong.

I have a div box that's going to be 500 in height and 500 in width, in it I will have text content when it's first loaded.  At the bottom I will have a button that says "click here."  When that button is clicked I want to change the background on the box and load images.

Please refer to the drawing below:

[image: So when the "click here" button is clicked, in the same box I just want to change the background and make the text that was there removed and load images using <img> tags]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd personally take a different more straight-forward approach. That is, if all you need is a few images you might as well fetch them in advance and hide them, skipping unnecessary server requests:

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fNgjp/1/)

CODE:

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="button_layer">
        <p>Some Text</p>
        <button>Click Me</button>
    </div>
    <div id="images_layer">
        <img src="http://mattat.org.il/wp-content/themes/matat/img/aminadav.jpg"/>
        <img src="http://mattat.org.il/wp-content/themes/matat/img/aminadav.jpg"/>
         <img src="http://mattat.org.il/wp-content/themes/matat/img/aminadav.jpg"/>
    </div>
   </div>
```

​     CSS:

```
#container {
width:500px;
height:500px;
background:grey;
}
#images_layer {
display:none;
}
```

JS:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
         $("#button_layer").hide();
        $("#images_layer").show();
        $("#container").css("background","yellow");
    })
  });
```

​

Comment: Thanks Matanya.  But how would i make the background color change on click as well?

Comment: One more thing is that I am having trouble make the javascript part work on my webpage.  What am I using to make sure the javascript loads.  This is how I am using it:  

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("button").click(function(){
     $("#button_layer").hide();
    $("#images_layer").show();
});​
</script>

Comment: you need to wrap it with `$(document).ready(function(){ // code });`, or put the code at the end of the document after the DOM elements have been loaded

Comment: I am sorry I am new to this so unclear what you mean and how i would go about it.  Can give me a sample as to how to do it?

Comment: Thanks.  I added your updated snippet but on click it wouldn't change anything.  How do I check for errors?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20846/discussion-between-matanya-and-ariel)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var images = 10;

$('button').on('click' , function(){
    var html = '';
    for(var i =0;i<images ; i++){
      html += '<img src="images/image-'+ images + '"></img>';   
    }

    $('.a').removeClass('a').addClass('b').html(html);

});​

​<div class="a">
   I am the initial div...
</div>

​<button>Click Me</button>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/ZJfuM/2/)**

Comment: Thanks Sushanth.  But two concerns.  How do I change the background color on click and second I will be loading images manually like <img src="/file/image.png"> rather than relying on php to call them.  How would I make this work?

Comment: You can just use add and remove class to get the work done.. Also I have not used php in my code anywhere.. Check updated fiddle

Comment: OK let me work on that.  If i have a button id i can just use button#id right?

Answer (score 1):

I would accomplish this task by capturing the click function, then loading some data into the div by requesting it from the server.

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET', //default anyway
        url: '/path/to/my/controller.ext',
        data: {'getImages' : true},
        success: function(data){
             $('.box').html(data); 
        }
    });
});
```

Then in the server side, we can capture the get request and return a string of images; this example is in PHP.

```
if(isset($_GET['getImages']) && TRUE === $_GET['getImages']):
    //build some string to pass images..
    $str = '<img src="path/to/my/first_img.ext"/><img src="path/to/my/second_img.ext"/><img src="path/to/my/third_img.ext"/><img src="path/to/my/fourth_img.ext"/><img src="path/to/my/fifth_img.ext"/>';
    echo $str;
endif;
```

If the request to the filename provided in our `.ajax()` call happens, then it will use a `GET` request to grab images. Our conditional checks for the existence and value of `getImages`. We build a string with images inside of it, and pass it back. the `success:function(data)` of our `ajax()` call handles the returned data. In this example. data is the `$str` we made in our `php conditional`. We simply change the HTML of the box to the string that we provided from the server.

Answer (score 0):

I uploaded an example for changing the background color with an animation:

http://jsfiddle.net/TBvcW/1/

It's made using CSS3, but browsers who don't support it will change the color without an animation. The key code for the animation of the color are these CSS properties:

```
-webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s, color 0.5s;
-mox-transition: background-color 0.5s, color 0.5s;
-o-transition: background-color 0.5s, color 0.5s;
transition: background-color 0.5s, color 0.5s;
```

Where, we are deciding which property will be animated when changed ( through CSS ), and how much time the animation will take.

You can even change the Height of the box and add the images as described in the other answers:

http://jsfiddle.net/TBvcW/2/

Cheers.